# How to make an english date format work in a french Excel?

Tags: excel, date, localization

I have an Excel file that must work for english & french computer.

I need to concatenate dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd, so for my english user, I need to do:

```
="your date = "&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

That works, but not in french Excel, where I need to do

```
="your date = "&TEXT(A1,"aaaa-mm-jj")
```

How can I print the same date to both my users, independently of theirs Excel langage locale?

[English TEXT function](https://support.office.com/fr-ch/article/fonction-TEXTE-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) vs [French TEXTE function](https://support.office.com/fr-ch/article/fonction-TEXTE-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c).

And yes, the date format string are localized...

Comment: One option is to use combination of `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY`. For day and month use `RIGHT("0" & DAY(...),2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the date in right format use:

```
=YEAR(A1) & "-" & RIGHT("0" & MONTH(A1),2) & "-" & RIGHT("0" & DAY(A1),2)
```

Comment: As long as we have only one date format it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I used to cope with this issue as follow assuming you're on a eng MSExcel:

```
1. I create a named formula (returns true when it's a fr region MSExcel)
   name: xlFR
   refers to: = text(Today(),"d") = "d"
   click OK
2. in your formula you decide on xlFR

ex: = Text(today(), if(xlFR,"jj-mm-aaaa","dd-mm-yyyy") )
```

That's it.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html) which seems to treat your issue :

> If you are using the TEXT worksheet function because it is part of a larger formula, then you can instruct the function itself to use a different language for its output. You do this by including a language code (formally called an LCID) within brackets, in this manner:
>
> =TEXT(A1,"[$-409]mmmm, yyyy")

Where you could specify the text to display according to the language you want.

Comment: It changes formula output language, but not parameter language.

Comment: Yeah I test that, but in fact it is just changing from "May" to "Mai", but you still need to use the right date format string...

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question. I'll leave the answer as it is for now, if it appears to be out of context i'll delete it later.

Comment: @CyrilGandon So the issue comes from the input, you might be able to use the same argument (LCID) to differenciate the command you're using, this might be a correct workaround solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use this vba function in my formulas:
Function DateToText(MyDate As Date)
DateToText = Format(MyDate, "DD/MM/YYYY")
End Function